# Log4j2 - create new log file

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I have configuration for save logs to file, but logs are append to existing content. I want to create always new file. How can I do that?

My log4j2.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <File name="File" fileName="out.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{ISO8601} %-5level] %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Root>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 4):

The FileAppender has a property named `append` which has a default value of *true*, so configure it like this:

```
<File name="File" fileName="out.log" append="false">
```

Documentation can be found at https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#FileAppender